# TensorFlow is returning an error when used in Laravel project, why?

Tags: php, python, laravel, shell, tensorflow

I run this command from bash (in my case zsh)

`python images/classify_image.py --image_file images/new_name.jpg`

And I am getting the correct output which is:

```
power drill (score = 0.97464)
hand blower, blow dryer, blow drier, hair dryer, hair drier (score = 0.00101)
carpenter's kit, tool kit (score = 0.00043)
screwdriver (score = 0.00034)
joystick (score = 0.00028)
```

But when I try to reproduce the same thing in my laravel project I am getting an error. My code inside my controller is this one:

```
$process = new Process('python images/classify_image.py --image_file images/new_name.jpg');

$process->run();
// executes after the command finishes
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
   throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}
dd($process->getOutput());
```

I am using Composer - [Process class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) in order to execute the command which comes built-in with Laravel. After running this code I am getting this error:

**The command "python images/classify_image.py --image_file images/new_name.jpg" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: /var/www/html/share/public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ Traceback (most recent call last): File "images/classify_image.py", line 46, in  import tensorflow as tf ImportError: No module named tensorflow**

Someone can give me hints, why I am getting this error? It seems like Laravel have no access to TensorFlow, but why I am able to execute this command from shell not in Laravel project?

Comment: TensorFlow is usually installed in some kind of contained environment, to which your regular user will have access - but php won't. I don't know if that's what's happening, but it's the most likely problem.

Comment: @JoelHinz, probably this is what it is happening, but can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an issue with Laravel. Can you run the command using exec()? Im guessing its a path issue. Process accepts a third parameter for env vars.

See if this helps:

```
$command = 'python images/classify_image.py --image_file images/new_name.jpg';
$cwd = null;
$envVars = [ 'HOME' => getEnv('HOME'), 'PATH' => getEnv('PATH') ];
$process = new Process($command, $cwd, $envVars);
$process->run();
// executes after the command finishes
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
   throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}
dd($process->getOutput());
```

**Edit:**

The reason was down to `tensorflow` not being globally available due to the the systems PATH variable not being passed to the shell.

Comment: and exec() is outputting an empty array - `[]`

Comment: and `'PATH' => getEnv('PATH')` is returning `false` as there is no such variable in getEnv()

Comment: type `echo $PATH` in terminal

Comment: are you using homestead or similar VM?

Comment: @LukeShowden, i am using regular Ubuntu 17.10. my PATH env returned this `/home/dimitar/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/home/dimitar/anaconda3/bin:/home/dimitar/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/dimitar/.composer/vendor/bin:/home/dimitar/bin:/home/dimitar/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:$HOME/anaconda3/bin:/snap/bin`

Comment: Just try pasting that into `'PATH' => 'here'` instead of using getEnv to see if that is the issue

Comment: it worked! can u please edit the answer so the PATH variable have to be the same as the shell PATH env. thanks!

Comment: Thats what I mean, I think you have a further underlying issue with your PHP conf if getEnv is returning an empty string. Glad its working!

Comment: In my case i had to only change this line of the code you have provided `$envVars = ['HOME' => getEnv('HOME'), 'PATH' => '/home/dimitar/anaconda3/bin'];`